# list methods of only the object/class in visual studio

Tags: visual-studio

Couple of questions:

1. It seems that `visual studio` is listing all the methods available instead of methods only of the selected object. Could I make `visual studio` list only the methods of the selected class/object?

[image]

2. I notice that method names have different symbols in front. Eg `db` has a cuboid, `dropDatabase` has a cube. What do they mean?

Comment: I'm not sure, but this is almost certainly VS Code...